# How can I deploy not only .jar file but also .properties file on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, jar

I have a server.jar file which I want to deploy on Heroku. When I run `heroku deploy:jar server.jar --app myapp`, heroku deploy only server.jar file, but I also want to deploy server.properties file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can package the property files inside the Jar file (if you use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) is straightforward).

If you need to update these values at runtime (when deploying on Heroku) you need to look at [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)